# What does this sentence mean?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, earth, moon

> "The acceleration of free fall on the surface of the Earth is 6 times its value on the surface of the Moon."

I interpreted it as:

> "The acceleration of free fall due to the Earth's gravitational field, on the surface of the Earth, is 6 times the acceleration due to the Earth's gravitational field, on the surface of the Moon."

But I realized there is another way:

> "The acceleration of free fall due to the Earth's gravitational field, on the surface of the Earth, is 6 times the acceleration due to the Moon's gravitational field, on the surface of the Moon."

This one would also make sense.

Which one is "obviously" the intended one? I don't think I'm seeing it.

Note: After solving the question I looked at the back of the book and the answer implies that the intended version is the second one.

Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your context, the second interpretation is correct. The fact is that falling objects accelerate both on Earth and on the Moon. The sentence is saying that the amount of this acceleration, regardless the source, is six times greater on Earth than on the Moon. In other words, things accelerate towards the surface of Earth six times faster than they accelerate towards the surface of the Moon, all things considered.

The reason the second interpretation is correct is that things fall towards the surface of the Moon due to the Moon's gravity. Therefore, the acceleration of falling objects on the Moon must be due to the Moon's gravity, obviously.